Can't able to get the id of the model instance in django when i connect the project to MongoDB
I am doing the simple CRUD in djnago project ,first i was working with sqlite that is by default in djnago ,every thing was working properly,but when i configure it with MongoDB ,now create and read operations are working properly ,but for update and delete ,i can't able to get the id of the instance to send it to url with request, getting the error ,,  ValueError at /employe/update/None

when i try this '<form action="{% url 'update' i.id %}" method="POST">' and when i try to use <form action="{% url 'update' i._id %}" method="POST"Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.>  _id as it is identifier in mongoDB ,then the syntax arrive comes that attribute can't start with '_',,

ValueError at /employe/update/None

when i try this '<form action="{% url 'update' i.id %}" method="POST">' and when i try to use <form action="{% url 'update' i._id %}" method="POST"Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.>  _id as it is identifier in mongoDB ,then the syntax arrive comes that attribute can't start with '_',,


What if you use .pk instead?

Can you share the corresponding model?

with .pk ,still the same error

this is the model "class Employee(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
email=models.EmailField()
age=models.IntegerField()
salary=models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.name    "


DId you retrieve the object from the database. Note that passing an i: Employee() will not work, since than the .id is indeed still None.

yeah i tried to retrieve it with email, and it works ,but still the id is None for also this retrieved object

and also can't delete the object from the admin panel of django,it also showing that id is"ValueError at /admin/Employee/employee/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.
"

Django's models have a .pk attribute that returns the primary key, regardless what field that contains the primary key.
So you can use:
{% url 'update' i.pk %}

i already tried i.pk but still the same error that id is getting None
